# DomXpath and foreach. How to get a preview of the captured elements?

Tags: php

I am learning to deal with `DOMXpath` in `php`. I was using `regex` (but I was discouraged here in the stack when for html capture). I confess that for me it is not so simple and the `DOM` has its limits (when there are spaces in tag names and also in error handling). If someone can help me with the command in php to get a preview of the captured elements and check if everything is right, I would appreciate it. If you have suggestions for improving the code, you're welcome to do so.The code below was based on a question in Stackoverflow itself.

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    // Deleting whitespace (if any)
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    @$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents ('http://www.imdb.com/search/title?certificates=us:pg_13&genres=comedy&groups=top_250'));
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    // Starting from the root element
    $grupos = $xpath->query(".//*[@class='lister-item mode-advanced']");
    // Creating an array and then looping with the elements to be captured (image, title, and link)
    $resultados = array();
    foreach($grupos as $grupo) {
        $i = $xpath->query(".//*[@class='loadlate']//@src", $grupo);
        $t = $xpath->query(".//*[@class='lister-item-header']//a/text()", $grupo);
        $l = $xpath->query(".//*[@class='lister-item-header']//a/@href", $grupo);

    $resultados[] = $resultado;

}
// What command should I use to have a preview of the results and check if everything is ok?
print_r($resultados);
```

Comment: First of all, I can't see what "$resultado" is, did you mean something like $resultados[] =  ['i' => $i, 't' => $t, 'l' => $l]; //? Second, what do you mean by 'preview'?

Comment: @konrados ($resultados[] = ['i' => $i, 't' => $t, 'l' => $l] is the correct form?) (preview = list of captured items.)

Comment: Not sure what you mean, you just copied my code and added brackets in weird places o_O :) Anyway, I posted an answer, I don't think a 'comment' would handle the entire code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so here your code with two corrections. First I'm adding a subarray to $resultados  with the elements, and seconds I'm making a foreach instead of print_r/var_dump

BTW, doesn't imdb offer an API?

```
    <?php 
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(-1);

    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    // Deleting whitespace (if any)
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents ('http://www.imdb.com/search/title?certificates=us:pg_13&genres=comedy&groups=top_250'));
    //$doc->loadHTML($HTML);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    // Starting from the root element
    $grupos = $xpath->query(".//*[@class='lister-item mode-advanced']");
    // Creating an array and then looping with the elements to be captured (image, title, and link)
    $resultados = array();
    foreach($grupos as $grupo) {
        $i = $xpath->query(".//*[@class='loadlate']//@src", $grupo);
        $t = $xpath->query(".//*[@class='lister-item-header']//a/text()", $grupo);
        $l = $xpath->query(".//*[@class='lister-item-header']//a/@href", $grupo);

    $resultados[] = ['i' => $i[0], 't' => $t[0], 'l' => $l[0]];

}
// What command should I use to have a preview of the results and check if everything is ok?
//var_dump($resultados);
foreach($resultados as $r){
    echo "\n-----------\n";
    echo $r['i']->value."\n";
    echo $r['t']->textContent."\n";
    echo $r['l']->value."\n";
}
```

You can play with it here:
https://3v4l.org/hal0G

Comment: Imdb offers api. I just used it as an example to learn DOMXpath.

I still can not see results on my localhost, even with your changes.

Comment: @AntonioOliveira - did you open the example link above, i.e. https://3v4l.org/hal0G ? Second, if you can't see the results, then what do you see?  Third, enable error reporting, I updated my code, i.e. added two lines at the top.

Comment: the problem is with the page capture by file_get_contents (or cURL). Using $HTML (offline) worked. Thanks!!